# How can I figure out if one List has different value than the other List

Tags: c#, for-loop, arraylist

I have two special List(defaultGeometry,changedGeometry) and I have one another method (AreCoordinatesEqual) which can compare coordinates and return boolean.

```
for (int i = 0; i < defaultGeometry.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < changedGeometry.Count; j++)
    {
        if (!AreCoordinatesEqual(defaultGeometry[i], changedGeometry[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

My question is; If, changedGeometry has even one different coordinate(or lets say value) from defaultGeometry then I should return false. Basically I want to match every changedGeometry coordinates with every defaultGeometry coordinates so that I will realize If any foreign value changedGeometry has. Please note that; defaultGeometry can have different values it's ok. So I tried some contain methods but I would like to use my method(AreCoordinatesEqual) in that case and nested loops looks the best solution. But any other ways are appreciated. I would be grateful for any help at this point. Thank you

Comment: `bool allIncluded = changedGeometry.All(defaultGeometry.Contains)`

Comment: This returns false in every case :/

Answer (score 1):

Linq appraoch with `Zip()` and `All()`

```
return defaultGeometry.Zip(changedGeometry,(d,c) => AreCoordinatesEqual(d,c)).All(x => x);
```

... or you just remove the second `for` loop in your own appraoch and add `return true;` at the end

Comment: I tried first line but it gives only false result. Can you describe a bit your second approach please?

Comment: Can you mak sure, that the `AreCoordinatesEqual` method doesn't return invalid results?

Answer (score 1):

I think 5th row's changedGeometry number is wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < defaultGeometry.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < changedGeometry.Count; j++)
    {
        if (!AreCoordinatesEqual(defaultGeometry[i], changedGeometry[**j**]))
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you.. But it compares the all values and when I remove one value from changedGeometry it return false even changedGeometry has no different value from defaultGeometry. Becuase indexes are shifting. So the whole method should return true when changedGeometry doesnt have any different value from defaultGeometry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to just use the `.Except()` method from LINQ.
The only condition is to make sure your entity implements the [IEqualityComparer interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0)

Here is a sample and its result with Points (which act as your coordinates):

```cs
using System.Drawing;

var oldPoints = new List<Point>()
{
    new Point(0, 0),
    new Point(1,1),
    new Point(2,2),
    new Point(3,3),
    new Point(4,4),
};
var newPoints = new List<Point>()
{
    new Point(0, 0),
    new Point(1,1),
    new Point(-2,-2),
    new Point(-3,-3),
    new Point(-4,-4),
};

var changedPoints = newPoints.Except(oldPoints);

var changedPointsCount = changedPoints.Count();
Console.WriteLine($"Number of point changed: {changedPointsCount}");
if(changedPointsCount > 0)
{
    foreach(var changedPoint in changedPoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"New point detected: X={changedPoint.X} # Y={changedPoint.Y}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number of point changed: 3
New point detected: X=-2 # Y=-2
New point detected: X=-3 # Y=-3
New point detected: X=-4 # Y=-4
```